# How does docker-compose create aliases for link ips

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ip, docker-compose, alias

when running docker-compose, all containers have network aliases to the ip of the other containers running in the network.
How are these aliases created ?

I need to recreate an alias in an nginx container within a Kubernetes cluster, because nginx conf doesn't allow environment variables and I reverse proxy requests to another container from there.
I would normally edit the /etc/hosts file, but since docker-compose doesn't, I'm wondering how is the alias created and if I could do it the same way within my kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a kubernetes cluster, there is a DNS server service deployed by default.

`kubectl get svc` should show the DNS service IP address.

You can find the DNS server IP address inside the containers `/etc/resolv.conf` file too.

See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for more info.

You can specify additional entries in container's `/etc/hosts` file using HostAliases. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/).

Snip:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I need to do, and we can set hostAliases in Deployment specs as well. Wondering now how to replace the hard-coded ip with a link to the related container service ip.

Concretely, I want my nginx container to access the php-fpm service (name stg-phpfpm-svc) as `php` from the nginx.conf for reverse proxying. Maybe I need to do something else, like dnsAliasing on the service ...

Comment: You should be able to use the service discovery. That's how different services in a k8s cluster communicate.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

> Containers for the linked service are reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified

This means if you have a docker-compose file like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
     links:
       - app1
     ...
  app1:
    ...
```

Then nginx is able to access the other container by `app1`.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I asked about how docker-compose does that aliasing in the back. My local docker-compose network works just fine, but it's a bit magic and hard to reproduce on kubernetes ...